# Add publish version to CSS and JS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, bundling-and-minification

I have my CSS and JS in my layout page.

I need to add a param string to the CSS and JS when I do changes and I upload them with these changes.

For example:

```
<environment names="Production">
    <link href="~/dist/mycss.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</environment>
```

To:

```
<environment names="Production">
    <link href="~/dist/mycss.bundle.css?param=withchanges" rel="stylesheet"/>
</environment>
```

What is the best way to do that? Has new ASP.NET 5 a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is a built in taghelper that is just for this purpose

```
<link href="~/dist/mycss.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

by adding the asp-append-version=true, a hash of the file contents will be automatically appended to the url so it will change if the file contents change.